# Create a Nurbs Circle Surface using python

Tags: python, scripting, nurbs-surface

I am trying to achieve the following [post](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?280367-NURBS-Circle-Pringles-chip-merging-the-circle&p=2296687&viewfull=1#post2296687)

I see doing this two ways.
Create a large circle and small circle and fill the inbetween.
Perform the same steps as the GUI programmatically, create NURBS Circle Surface, and  extrude into a smaller circle.

What is the best way to do this? Do the vectors have to be manually inserted to create a square or is there something in python that will create the nurbs circle surface with radius and origin?